# Reading a MySQL query with Python where output is empty

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, mysql-python

I'm trying to connect MySQL with python in order to automate some reports. By now, I'm just testing the connection. Seems it's working but here comes the problem: the output from my Python code is different from the one that I get in MySQL.

Here I attach the query used and the output that I can find in MySQL:

The testing query for the Python connection:

```
SELECT accountID 
FROM Account
WHERE accountID in ('340','339','343');
```

The output from MySQL (using Dbiever). For this test, the column chosen contains integers:

```
  accountID
1   339
2   340
3   343
```

Here I attach the actual output from my Python code:

```
today:
20200811
Will return true if the connection works:
True
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [accountID]
Index: []
```

In order to help you understand the problem, please find attached my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import pymysql
import paramiko
from datetime import date, time

tiempo_inicial = time()

today = date.today()
today= today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
print('today:')
print(today)


#from paramiko import SSHClient
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

**(part that contains all the connection information, due to data protection this part can't be shared)**

print('will return true if connection works:')
print(conn.open)


query = '''SELECT accountId
FROM Account
WHERE accountID in ('340','339','343');'''


            
data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)

print(data)
conn.close()
```

Under my point of view doesn't have a sense this output as the connection is working and the query it's being tested previously in MySQL with a positive output. I tried with other columns that contain names or dates and the result doesn't change.

Any idea why I'm getting this "Empty DataFrame" output?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should use numbers instead of strings `(340, 339, 343)`

Comment: we can't test it so it is hard to say what is the problem. The only idea you connect to different database - without data.

Comment: Hello @furas, I tried the solution you purpose and there is no change on the output. I'm 100% sure the database which I'm connected is the same as the only I'm quering

Comment: maybe first check `SELECT` without `WHERE`  to see what you get. You import `pymysql` so you could also test query with `pymysql` before you use it with `pandas`